# Flash movie overlaps relatively positioned menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress, formatting, z-index

I've been working on a site and noticed a problem with the Flash slider (CU3ER) overlapping the menu bar. I've tried different z-index settings to keep the drop down menu on top, but nothing works.

The drop down menu is visible while the Flash movie loads, but after it finishes loading it gets pushed behind.

http://pivotpointconsulting.com.s139330.gridserver.com/

How It Should Look: [image: http://i.imgur.com/Cw4PF.png]

How It Looks: [image: http://imgur.com/Cw4PF,O93Gm#1]

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to add param "wmode"->"opaque" to your Flash movie.

```
  params: {
    wmode: 'opaque',
    bgcolor : '#ffffff'

  }
```

Comment: `opaque` works, and is usually a better choice. You only need `transparent` when the background of the Flash movie must be transparent.

Comment: @thirtydot you're right, it's been a long time since i embedded my last flash movie.

Comment: @TrentonScott I also tried this locally (downloaded the webpage), and it does solve the problem - sure you have no typos?

Comment: No typos, I'm really scratching my head. Check the page here (view source and search for 'opaque' to see where I added it): http://pivotpointconsulting.com.s139330.gridserver.com/

Comment: the bgcolor: #ffffff assumes you want the background to be white.

Answer (score 0):

follow these tutorial will fix the problem. see http://shivasoft.in/view_tutorial.php?id=132, it sees the mian point is:

```
#id{position:absolute; z-index:1;}
```

Comment: Tried setting the menu to z-index 1 and slideshow to z-index 5. Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Hy,
did you add `position:absolute;` to both elements ? Because that is required for using `z-index` !

Answer (score 0):

Add this under the object tag.

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
```

I got it from here. https://wiki.base22.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=37683366
It works!